# Template argument for non-type parameter must be an expression

Tags: c++, templates

Why is the following code wrong?

```
template <typename T, int N>
struct Vector {
    T data[N];
};

struct Dynamic {
};

template <typename T>
struct Vector<T, Dynamic> {
    T* data;
};
```

I tried to instantiate the code with `Vector<int, Dynamic> obj;` and it didn't work

> error: template argument for non-type template parameter must be an expression

Why? I'm passing a type and I thought that was a valid template specialization.

How can I use two templates and having one that requests N and one that doesn't if marked with `Dynamic` ?

Comment: The primary template expects an `int`, but you are providing a `Dynamic` in the specialisation, so that's invalid.

Comment: Doesn't the error message say exactly what's wrong? `Dynamic` is not an expression, it's a type name. It's not a value of `int`.

Comment: @KerrekSB okay, but why won't [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b131d123ca803a5) work then? This is another template, completely unrelated

Comment: @Dean The two templates are not unrelated since the second one is a specialization of the first one.

Comment: @Dean: That's the same problem. Never mind that partial specialization defines a new template, but you are trying to define it *in terms of* a template instantiation that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
template <typename T, int N>
struct Vector {
    T data[N];
};
```

Here in your primary template class, `T` must be a [type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Type_template_parameter), (`int, short, class-type, etc`)... `N` is a [non-type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter), and must be an expression that evaluates to an `int` type (a number).

```
struct Dynamic {
};

template <typename T>
struct Vector<T, Dynamic> {
    T* data;
};
```

`Dynamic` is a type. Not an `int` as specified in your primary template

---

Based on your primary template class, you can only specialize the second template parameter of `Vector` with an `int`. Eg.

```
template <typename T>
struct Vector<T, 1> {
    T* data;
};

template <typename T>
struct Vector<T, 35> {
    T* data;
};

template <typename T>
struct Vector<T, constExpressionThatReturnsAnInt> {
    T* data;
};

...etc
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `Dynamic` to specialization `Vector` because `Dynamic` is a *class* and your primary template expect an `int`. What you want is probably something like:

```
#include <limits>

constexpr size_t Dynamic = std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max();

template <typename T, size_t N>
struct Vector {
    T data[N];
};

template <typename T>
struct Vector<T, Dynamic> {
    T* data;
};

Vector<int, 10> static_array;
Vector<int, Dynamic> dynamic_array;
```

Here `Dynamic` is a `constexpr` of the correct type (`size_t`), so you can specialize your template. You will simply not be able to create static array of size `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()` (which should not be an issue).