# Why won't templates 'overload' over template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates

Since people don't read and compare code in a grep-like way, I'm immediately stating that this is NOT a duplicate of [Template argument for non-type parameter must be an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880517/template-argument-for-non-type-parameter-must-be-an-expression) but another one I thought of AFTER reading it. Therefore please read this as a whole and don't just look at the class names.

```
template <typename T, int N>
struct Vector {
    T data[N];
};

struct Dynamic {
};

template <typename T, Dynamic>
struct Vector {
    T* data;
};
```

I'd like two templates: one that receives a compile-time integer, another one that receives a type used as a tag.

This won't work though since for whatever reason, the second template is interpreted as a specialization (or redefinition?) of the first one.

**Why can't template be disambiguated over template parameters? Any logical / compiling reason for this?**

Comment: You can keep asking, but you won't get the answer you want :-S The language doesn't let you do that.

Comment: Uh I'm just curious, sorry if this looks like a repost. I just can't see why templates overloading (with different parameter types, e.g. type and non-type) would be a bad idea

Comment: Undoubtedly, but this isn't a website for musing about good ideas.

Comment: I am confused on what you want to do there, as there is no `template <typename T,typename U> struct Vector` but you try to somehow pass `Dynamic` to it as the second parameter

Comment: You should discuss this on the std-proposals or std-discussions mailing list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of your question, the answer is:  "because".  Not every single feature is a part of the language.

In terms of what you seem to be trying to achieve though, you could try template specialisation (although I personally haven't used it with non-type arguments before, I see you reason why it wouldn't work).

```
template <typename T, int N>
struct Vector
{
    T data[N];
};

const int Dynamic = INT_MAX;

template <typename T>
struct Vector<T, Dynamic>
{
    T* data;
};
```

Comment: Yeah this works, but I don't see why I can't have two templates, one accepting a `typename, int` and one with signature `typename,typename`. Those are quite distinguishable

Comment: I guess it's just obscure enough that it hasn't become a priority to implement.  Spending lots of time with C++ often becomes a deep dive into finding workarounds that try to emulate what you *really* want to do.

Answer (score 4):

Because that's not how the language works; it's as simple as that!

Templates are defined once then optionally specialised later. They do not have "overload" semantics.

Comment: Is there a proposal to have this? I don't understand why it wouldn't be beneficial.

Comment: @Dean: I don't understand why it would be. Feel free to write and submit such a proposal yourself, but don't expect it to go anywhere.